# Difference between declaration of object in Swift

Tags: swift, declaration

I apologize in advance for a possible duplicate but since I do not know the names of these declarations I was not able to find any answers to simular questions.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain the difference between these to object declarations to me:

1. `var objectname: Classname!`
2. `var objectname = Classname()`

Both are an instance of the class `Classname` right? So when do I use the first declaration and when the second? And why?

Comment: Scan [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+difference+declaration) and you'll answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `var objectname: Classname!`

This declares an object of type `Classname` but does not give it a value. If you were to try to access this value, it would be `nil`. Because having no value in Swift is not allowed, the `!` tells the compiler that the variable will have a value when it is accessed. For iOS development, I would not recommend using the first declaration because it is unsafe. I would use `var objectname: Classname?` which creates the same variable but does not assume that it has a value. You could use this type like this:

```
var objectname: Classname?
if let obj = objectname {
    // do something with obj (the unwrapped value of objectname)
}
```

If `objectname` has a value, then the if statement executes, otherwise it doesn't.

2. `var objectname: Classname()`

This declares a variable of type Classname and initializes it at the same time. So while the first statement is `nil`, the second statement represents an object of type `Classname`. You should use this statement when creating an instance variable.